# How to change a reference column to be polymorphic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration, ruby-on-rails-2

My model (Bar) already has a reference column, let's call it `foo_id` and now I need to change `foo_id` to `fooable_id` and make it polymorphic.

I figure I have two options:

- Create new reference column `fooable` which is polymorphic and migrate the ID's from `foo_id`  (What would be the best way to migrate these? Could I just do `Bar.each { |b| b.fooable_id = b.foo_id }?`
- Rename `foo_id` to `fooable_id` and add `polymorphic` to `fooable_id`. How to add polymorpic to an existing column?

Comment: Oh wow, you're still using Rails 2? Is this real or a typo?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**1.** Change the name of **foo_id** to **fooable_id** by renaming it in a migration like:

```
rename_column :bars, :foo_id, :fooable_id
```

**2.** and add polymorphism to it by adding the required **foo_type** column in a migration:

```
add_column :bars, :fooable_type, :string
```

**3.** and in your model:

```
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :fooable, 
    polymorphic: true
end
```

**4.** Finally seed the type of you already associated type like:

```
Bar.update_all(fooable_type: 'Foo')
```

Read [Define polymorphic ActiveRecord model association!](http://chris-on-rails.blogspot.de/2014/08/define-polymorphic-activerecord-models.html)

Comment: The final step could be rewritten as `Bar.update_all(fooable_type: 'Foo')`, right?

Comment: This doesn't work if you use foreign_key (default for generated migrations for reference). See updated anwer below.

Answer (score 18):

**Update for Rails >= 4.2**

TLDR

- add new reference
- copy reference ids
- remove old reference

So the migration is:

```
def change
  add_reference :bars, :fooable, polymorphic: true
  reversible do |dir|
    dir.up { Bar.update_all("fooable_id = foo_id, fooable_type='Foo'") }
    dir.down { Bar.update_all('foo_id = fooable_id') }
  end
  remove_reference :bars, :foo, index: true, foreign_key: true
end
```

**Background**

Current Rails generates references with index and foreign_key, which is a good thing.
This means that the answer of @Christian Rolle is no longer valid as after renaming `foo_id` it leaves a foreign_key on `bars.fooable_id` referencing `foo.id` which is invalid for other `fooable`s.

Luckily, also the migrations evolve, so undoable migrations for references do exist.

Instead of renaming the reference id, you need to create a new reference and remove the old one.
What's new is the need to migrate the ids from the old reference to the new one.
This could be done by a

```
Bar.find_each { |bar| bar.update fooable_id: bar.foo_id }
```

but this can be very slow when there are already many relations. `Bar.update_all` does it on database level, which is much faster.

Of course, you should be able to roll back the migration, so when using foreign_keys the complete migration is:

```
def change
  add_reference :bars, :fooable, polymorphic: true
  reversible do |dir|
    dir.up { Bar.update_all("fooable_id = foo_id, fooable_type='Foo'") }
    dir.down { Bar.update_all('foo_id = fooable_id') }
  end
  remove_reference :bars, :foo, index: true, foreign_key: true
end
```

Remember that during rollback, change is processed from bottom to top, so foo_id is created before the `update_all` and everything is fine.

Comment: THANK YOU! This was really helpful. Question about the down portion — shouldn't it explicitly filter for `fooable`s of `type='Foo'`, as there might be repeat ids between Foo another class which may have implemented Fooable since the change to polymorphic, right?

Comment: It might be useful to clear all polymorphic references to other types than Foo, as the other classes should no longer exist when you switch off polymorphic. This should be done in later migrations (reverted earlier :-) that add the other classes. So kind of YES, BUT...

Comment: Super useful migration - just used it 5x in one of my projects

Answer (score 3):

One small change I would make is to the migration:

```
#db/migrate/latest.rb
class Latest
  def change
    rename_column :bars, :foo_id, :fooable_id
    add_column :bars, :fooable_type, :string, after: :id, default: 'Foo'
  end
end
```

This would eliminate the need to do a data migration.

Update: this will work on rails 3 and up. According to the question the original base class is implied to be Foo.

Comment: Umm, this isn't valid in Rails 2.3 and also this eliminates the possibility of using the untyped baseclass

Answer (score 0):

In reference to your question specifically, here's what I'd do:

All the data in your `Bar` model is going to be stored in reference to the `Bar` model. This means that if you change the `foo_id` attribute in your model, you'll be able to just populate the `bar_type` attribute you need to add (as they'll all be able to reference the same model)

The way to do this is as follows:

> 1. Create migration for `foo_id` > `fooable_id`
> 2. Insert a `fooable_type` column
> 3. In rails console, loop through all existing records of `Bar`, filling the `fooable_type` column

First things first:

> $ rails g migration ChangeFooID

```
#db/migrate/latest.rb
class Latest
   def change
      rename_column :bars, :foo_id, :fooable_id
      add_column :bars, :fooable_type, :string, after: :id
   end
end
```

This will create the various columns for you. Then you just need to be able to cycle through the records & change the `type` column:

> rails c

```
Bar.find_each do |bar|
  bar.update(barable_type: "Foo")
end
```

This will allow you to change the type of your columns, giving you the ability to associate all the current records with the respective records.

---

**Polymorphism**

You'll be able to [use the Rails docs as a reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) as to how to associate your models:

```
#app/models/foo.rb
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :bars, as: :barable
end

#app/models/bar.rb
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :foo, polymorphic: true
end
```

[image]

Comment: **bar.update(barable_type: "Foo")** won't work, since update is private. I guess you meant ActiveRecord#update_attribute.